# Yield in Ruby and how blocks work

Tags: ruby

I am new here and I hope I will get answer to my question.
I have three classes.

1. Runner
2. Writer
3. Company

In runner class I have

```
writer = Writer.new(directory + datasource.downcase + ".xml")
ds = ("Sitemap::" + datasource).constantize.new(country_version, directory, country_host)
writer.fill do
            ds.yield_data {|entry| writer.write_entry(entry)}
end
```

Yeild_data is in class Company

write_entry is in class Writer

Following is the class Company code

```
  class Company

    def initialize(country_version, directory, country_host)
      @country_version = country_version
      @directory = directory
      @country_host = country_host
    end

    def yield_data
      ::Company.find_each(:conditions => {:country_version_id => @country_version.id}) do |company|
       output = yield entry(company)
       puts output
      end
    end

    private
    def entry(company)
      {
        :url => ActionController::Integration::Session.new.url_for(:controller => 'companies', :action => 'show', :company_name => company.name, :host => @country_host.value),
        :frequency => 0.8,
        :priority => 'monthly',
        :lastmod => company.updated_at
      }
    end
  end
```

Following is the class Writer

```
 class Writer
    include ActionController::UrlWriter

    def initialize(filepath)
      @filepath = RAILS_ROOT + filepath
      @xml_document = Nokogiri::XML::Document.new
    end

    def fill
      File.open(@filepath,"w") do |f|
        f.write(%[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n])
        f.write(%[<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">\n])
        yield self
        f.write(%[</urlset>])
        f.close
      end
    end

    def write_entry(entry)
      node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new("url", @xml_document)
      node["loc"]= entry[:url]
      node["lastmod"]= entry[:lastmod].to_s
      node["changefreq"] =  entry[:frequency].to_s
      node["priority"] = entry[:priority].to_s
      node.to_xml
      #@filepath.write(node)
    end
  end
```

Kindly answer me the following questions:

1. what will yeild entry(company) return (in company class)
2. what will yield self return (in writer class)
3. How can I write the node to xml file

Comment: Can't you just *run* the code and see what it returns?

Comment: I run the code but i m confused with the output?

Comment: actually there is block inside another block and it makes me confuse

Comment: I think you'll get a better answer if you reduce your block handling questions to a minimal example (without all of your application's logic) and split your xml question into a separate question

Comment: Frederick Cheung just tell me how can i write the result into the xml

Comment: or just explain me the flow of runner class ... especially the blocks portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just look in what scope you are. Remember, `self` is implied :

1. we are in an instance method, and it yields `self.entry(company)`. So it will return the output of a call to `entry(company)` on the present instance ( wich seems to be `ds` in the first code you posted )
2. still an instance method, so it will return `self`, a.k.a. the instanciated `Writer` on which `fill` is called, that is your `writer` object in the first code
3. as @Frederick said, you should ask about the XML in another question and keep your question concise. Please read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to know more about how to use this site. Welcome to the community !

**EDIT :** some help with the blocks

blocks are somewhat like anonymous functions.

whenever you do this :

```
some_method {|block_args| some_block }
```

just imagine you pass a function to `some_method`, and that function needs `block_args`. Now when you do :

```
def some_method
  yield some_args
end
```

just imagine you call the block with `block_args` = `some_args`. It really helps to imagine a block like a simplified method signature, with no method name but with a list of arguments. In fact, this is like doing :

```
 def some_method
   my_block( some_args )
 end

 def my_block( block_args )  
   # do something and return the result
 end
```

with the notable exception that a block is bound to the context in which it is called:

```
 class Myclass
   def hi
     # we are in an instance method, so self = the instance on which it is called
     OtherClass.new.hello { self.name }
   end

   def name
     "world"
   end
 end

 class OtherClass
   def hello
     puts "hello #{ yield } !" # here, we call the block without args
   end
 end

 # self.name is evaluated in the context it is called, so :
 >> Myclass.new.hi
 "hello world !"
 => nil
```

now just imagine that `yield` is a function name that stands for the block ; if the block returns something, you can use it as the return of any other function. A little example with some dummy implementation of the already existing `Enumerable#map` method :

```
 def map
   result = []
   self.each do |element|
     result << yield element # store in an array the result of the block for each element...
   end
   result                    # and return it
 end

>> [1,2,3].map {|e| e * e }
=> [1,4,9]
```

Comment: If we look at the blocks in runner class... the inner block returns all the entries and the outer block (ds.yield_data{}) returns me an instance of class Company ? m i right or not? if yes how can i use it to write all these entries to my xml file which i create in fill method?

Comment: No. the inner block (`{|entry| writer.write_entry(entry)}`) is fed with results from `entry(company)` and returns a XML node to the `output` variable in your `yield_data` method ; it is then displayed with `puts` so `yield_data` returns `nil` (`puts` almost always returns `nil`). The outer block is somewhat useless : you feed it with the `writer` instance though you don't use that instance in your block + your blocks returns `nil` + you don't use the return of the inner block inside the `fill` method, which only returns the result of the file closing.

Comment: can u plz correct the code to write the xml ? I will be thankful

Comment: How can I use the return of inner block in fill method? because the inner block returns me all the entries for my xml file but i dont knw how to write it using the fill method, your help will be appreciated... Thanks

Comment: as you seem to have trouble with the blocks, i added some explanations. As for the xml thing, just a lead : in yield_date, use `map` instead of `each` to collect in an array all the results of `entry(company)`, then pass this array to `Writer#fill` in which you will perform a write operation in the file for each element of the array.

Comment: in yield_data I used find_each to get the collection in batches for  efficient use of memory. is yield entry(company) dont contain all the entires needed for xml? i print it n it gives me all the entries for the xml... wat i want is to pass all these to fill method and I dont know how to do it :(

Comment: ... as i said, you inner block **returns nothing**. You have to adapt you `yield_data` method to return something if you want to use it ! Then again, don't overuse the blocks, simply pass your data to your `fill` method as arguments. Please at least try to understand what i wrote... and i strongly advise you to learn more about ruby & OOP as you seem really confused with all that stuff.

Comment: **NO**. `entry(company)` is the result of **a single call of the block**, and you execute the block for **each result of `find_each`**. It does this : for each element in a collection, call the block with 1 element as argument, then call it with the next element, etc... in your method, every time the block is called you store the result in the same variable, overwriting it. use [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

Comment: def yield_data
      data = []
      ::Company.find_each(:conditions => {:country_version_id => @country_version.id}) do |company|
        data << yield(entry(company))
      end
      return data
    end

Comment: Now I store my entries in an array and yield_data method return tht array ?

Comment: yes. You can use `map` to do exactly the same thing, see link in previous comment.